# Is it possible to check if iCloud KeyChain is enabled in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, settings, icloud, keychain

I would like to check if a user has iCloud Keychain enabled on an iOS device, in order to prompt them if they haven't so they can switch it on to allow sync of data.
Can anyone advise me how to achieve this programmatically?

Is there any way to read the settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: No sorry! It seems that you can't, as the keychain will sync locally if iCloud is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question to Apple Developer Technical Support and got the answer that there is no API for this.

Comment: Thanks @Cenny. Interesting to hear.